# How to limit number of game plays in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing a game for iPhone with an in App purchase.  The game can be played in several modes.  I want to make one mode limited by how many times it can be played in a day unless the user upgrades with the in App purchase.  The user can still play in the other modes as many times as he wants without purchasing the upgrade.  If I keep track of the number of times he has played and save it as local data, he can just delete the app and re-install it, and the number of plays is reset.

Any ideas on how I could implement this limitation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the count in the keychain because that isn't deleted when the app is deleted.

Comment: Lol, just as I post my answer, I forget about deletion. Gg.